# How to handle unknown child routes in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Current configuration of routes (@angular-2.0.0-rc.1 router-deprecated)

RootComponent routes configuration:

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent, useAsDefault: true},
  {path: '/products/:category/...', name: 'ProductCategory', component: ProductComponent},
  {path: '/products/...', name: 'Product', component: ProductComponent}
])
```

Product component route configuration:

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/', name: 'ProductList', component: ProductListComponent, useAsDefault: true},
  {path: '/:id', name: 'ProductItem', component: ProductItemComponent},
])
```

When user navigates to `ProductList` path will be `/products` and when we open `ProductItem` `/products/200`.

Problem: need to implement subcategories, so when user first goes to `ProductList`, then navigates to one of the subcategories and path changes to `/products/nameOfProductCategory`.

Possible that `productCategory` has another one category. At the end user goes to `productItem`.

Comment: Please try to improve your question. I don't think things like `&` instead of `and` are appropriate here. This is not a casual chat. Also it's quite unclear what the actual problem is you try to solve. Can you please elaborate a bit more and add concrete code examples of routes and component you have and how they are connected. Thanks.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks for a help, I have updated question, hope it will help to understand problem

Comment: It's much better know and I think I understand what you want to do but what is the problem you face? What doesn't work?

Comment: With this routes config if I open app with 'products/subcategory/2259' no route navigation happens. I think this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665124/wildcard-selector-in-the-middle-in-angular-2-router/34708306 is very close to my problem

Comment: You don't have a route where `subcategory` can match.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have updated my question and included category. I am able to navigate to category now if path looks like '/products/subcategory'. Here is the problem, app will have paths like these '/products/subcategory/subsubcategory', '/products/subcategory/subsubcategory/subsubcategory'

Comment: There is no way for the router to distinguish between `/products/category` and `/products/id`. You could use regex routes like explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36154766/217408 to distinguish between `id` and `category`.

Comment: Seems like it's not possible via Router configuration, thx anyway.